# Java - Set Variable Contents as New Variable Name

Tags: java, string, variables, for-loop

```
println("This program allows you to enter your exam results!");
    int n0 = readInt("How many exam results do you have? ");
    for (int n=1; n<=n0; n++) {
        String r0 = "r"+n;
        int result = readInt("Result "+n+": ");
        println(r0);
    }
```

I am new to java and I was wondering if it would be possible for me to set 'String r0' variable's contents as 'int result' variable's name (instead of result).

I wish to do so as my program will have multiple 'int result's and I will need to use each individual one later on for arithmetic purposes.

Comment: No, in a compiled language like Java you can't do this. At runtime there's no local variable names, just stack locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** First **do not declare** `r0 as String` as you **intend to use it as** `integer`, but declare it as `int`, ya offcourse you can convert
       **string to integer** using `Integer.parseInt()`.

**eg:**

```
String r0 = "10";
int r = Integer.parseInt(r0);
```

**2.** I will advice you to use **Collection framework** for storing of **mulitple data** in java as it gives great **flexibilty**. Use `ArrayList<Integer>`.

**eg:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int n=1; n<=10; n++) {

      arr.add(n);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you really need to do is have a collection or *array* of results. Anytime you think you need something like:

```
int r0 = ...;
int r1 = ...;
int r2 = ...;
```

etc. then it's good indication that you're looking at some sort of collection.

So in the above example, you'd build an array of *size number of exam results*, and then populate each element of the array in turn.

Here's the [Java array tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). It's also worth looking at the [Java collection tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html), if only to compare/contrast.

Comment: How will I change the array number for every 'for' loop?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could, I don't imagine that would be a very good idea! It would be a nightmare to get to them to refer back to them later on.

In your situation, I would just recommend using an array of `int`s for your results instead.

Answer (score 0):

Below I have A program that will work. I would copy the code and try and rewrite it yourself to make sure you fully understand what is going on.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arrays 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Initialize Variables
        int examCount = 0;
        double examSum = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        // Prompt The user For Number Of Exams And Recieve Value
        System.out.print("Number Of Exams?  ");
        examCount = input.nextInt();


        // Create An Array That Is The Length Of The Number Of Exams And Holds Double Values
        double[] exams = new double[examCount];


        // Read In All Exam Scores. A For Loop Is Used Because You Know How Many Scores There Are
        for (int i = 0; i < examCount; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Exam Score:  ");
            exams[i] = input.nextDouble();
        }


        // Print Out All Of The Scores
        for (int i = 0; i < examCount; i++)
            System.out.println("Exam #" + (i+1) + "\t" + exams[i]);


        // Sum All Of The Exam Scores
        for (int i = 0; i < examCount; i++)
            examSum += exams[i];


        // Print Out An Average Of All Of The Scores
        System.out.println("Exam Average:  " + examSum / examCount);
    }
}
```